# React native google admob error?

Tags: react-native, native, jsx, admob

good morning everyone,

**steps i took:**

`npm install --save react-native-admob@next,
npm install`

then i went on implementing admob in my app, bear in mind i am using expo SDK,

the code look like this:

```
import {AdMobBanner} from 'react-native-admob';
....
render(){
return(
<AdMobBanner
              adSize="fullBanner"
              adUnitID="ca-app-pub-123456789/12321312"
              testDevices={[AdMobBanner.simulatorId]}
              onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
            />
)
}
```

**the error is :**

invariant violation native component for RNGADBannerView does not exist

i did pull an all nighter, and still couldn't figure it out! 
please can anyone help.

Comment: Admob requires native component to work. It will not work with expo apps. You can create app using react-native init

Comment: You can have a look at it https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/admob use this admob

Comment: thank you for response, i was importing admob from react-native-admob instead of admob from expo, since i am working with expo SDK

Answer (score 1):

Go To

/node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.java

```
 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    sendEvent(EVENT_VIDEO_COMPLETED, null);
  }
```

Delete @override Only

You can refer to this link:
https://react-native-solutions.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-create-react-native-app-with.html

Comment: thanks a cach clean and reverted to using yarn instead of npm, recently npm is causing a lot fo problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. `react-native link` worked for me.

For more details please check this.
https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/235

Comment: I was using expo sdk for development which comes with admob in Danger Zone. I ended up using it instead of the standalone npm package.